# How to rewrite an Oracle SQL Developer query to work on SQL server

Tags: sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a new job, but now I have to work with SQL Server instead of Oracle SQL Developer. The way I outer join tables does not work anymore. I need one good example how it works with SQL Server and multiple tables.

This is how I would write the query the old way (Oracle SQL developer).

```
select distinct DTE24.CONDSRT, DTE24.CONTROLE, DTE24.WAARDEBEG, totaal.totaalx, totaal1.totaalof1, totaal2.totaalof2

from 
[RT_IPOIKAZ_ODS].[WinIKAZ].[DTE24],

(select CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG, count(WAARDEBEG)totaalx
from [RT_IPOIKAZ_ODS].[WinIKAZ].[DTE24]
where CONTROLE = 12885
AND DTE24.DATAFVOER = 0
and CONDSRT = 'PRESCODE' 
and OFNIVO in (1,2)
group by CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG)totaal,

(select CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG, count(WAARDEBEG)totaalof1
from [RT_IPOIKAZ_ODS].[WinIKAZ].[DTE24]
where CONTROLE = 12885
AND DTE24.DATAFVOER = 0
and CONDSRT = 'PRESCODE' 
and OFNIVO = 1
group by CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG)totaal1,

(select CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG, count(WAARDEBEG)totaalof2
from [RT_IPOIKAZ_ODS].[WinIKAZ].[DTE24]
where CONTROLE = 12885
AND DTE24.DATAFVOER = 0
and CONDSRT = 'PRESCODE' 
and OFNIVO = 2
group by CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG)totaal2

where DTE24.CONTROLE=totaal.CONTROLE
and DTE24.CONTROLE=totaal1.CONTROLE
and DTE24.CONTROLE=totaal2.CONTROLE
and DTE24.WAARDEBEG=totaal.WAARDEBEG(+)
and DTE24.WAARDEBEG=totaal1.WAARDEBEG(+)
and DTE24.WAARDEBEG=totaal2.WAARDEBEG-(+)
order by 3
```

The bottom piece of the above query doesn't work any more (+). I have to join the tables differently. I tried it with one table with only one join like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DTE24.CONDSRT,
    DTE24.CONTROLE,
    DTE24.WAARDEBEG,
    totaal.totaalx
FROM [RT_IPOIKAZ_ODS].[WinIKAZ].[DTE24]
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG, COUNT(WAARDEBEG) totaalx
    FROM[RT_IPOIKAZ_ODS].[WinIKAZ].[DTE24]
    WHERE CONTROLE = 12885
    AND DTE24.DATAFVOER = 0
    AND CONDSRT = 'PRESCODE' 
    AND OFNIVO in (1,2)
    GROUP BY CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG
) totaal
ON DTE24.CONTROLE = totaal.CONTROLE 
WHERE DTE24.CONTROLE = 12885
AND DTE24.DATAFVOER = 0
```

But I don't know how to join all the tables and how to LEFT OUTER JOIN the `WAARDEBEG` from all `totaal` tables.

Please can you help?

Comment: Please research SQL ANSI-92 standard joins.. As a standard, it's used by all major database brands...

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, outer joins (I assume you want left outer joins) are written using the syntax `<source> LEFT OUTER JOIN <source> ON`. Therefore, a rewritten version of your Oracle SQL to work with SQL Server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DTE24.CONDSRT,
    DTE24.CONTROLE,
    DTE24.WAARDEBEG,
    totaal.totaalx,
    totaal1.totaalof1,
    totaal2.totaalof2
FROM [RT_IPOIKAZ_ODS].[WinIKAZ].[DTE24],
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG, COUNT(WAARDEBEG) AS totaalx
    FROM [RT_IPOIKAZ_ODS].[WinIKAZ].[DTE24]
    WHERE CONTROLE = 12885
    AND DTE24.DATAFVOER = 0
    AND CONDSRT = 'PRESCODE' 
    AND OFNIVO in (1,2)
    GROUP BY CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG
) AS totaal ON DTE24.CONTROLE = totaal.CONTROLE AND DTE24.WAARDEBEG = totaal.WAARDEBEG
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG, COUNT(WAARDEBEG) AS totaalof1
    FROM [RT_IPOIKAZ_ODS].[WinIKAZ].[DTE24]
    WHERE CONTROLE = 12885
    AND DTE24.DATAFVOER = 0
    AND CONDSRT = 'PRESCODE' 
    AND OFNIVO = 1
    GROUP BY CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG
) AS totaal1 ON DTE24.CONTROLE = totaal1.CONTROLE AND DTE24.WAARDEBEG = totaal1.WAARDEBEG
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG, COUNT(WAARDEBEG) AS totaalof2
    FROM [RT_IPOIKAZ_ODS].[WinIKAZ].[DTE24]
    WHERE CONTROLE = 12885
    AND DTE24.DATAFVOER = 0
    AND CONDSRT = 'PRESCODE' 
    AND OFNIVO = 2
    GROUP BY CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG
) AS totaal2 ON DTE24.CONTROLE = totaal2.CONTROLE AND DTE24.WAARDEBEG = totaal2.WAARDEBEG

ORDER BY 3
...
```

Also, rather than repeating this bit in each sub-query:

```
FROM [RT_IPOIKAZ_ODS].[WinIKAZ].[DTE24]
WHERE CONTROLE = 12885
AND DTE24.DATAFVOER = 0
AND CONDSRT = 'PRESCODE'
```

you could use a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) to get the set of data that you wish to work with in each sub-query, and just apply the one WHERE condition that is different between them. E.g.

```
WITH SourceData AS
(
    SELECT CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG, OFNIVO
    FROM [RT_IPOIKAZ_ODS].[WinIKAZ].[DTE24]
    WHERE CONTROLE = 12885
    AND DATAFVOER = 0 
    AND CONDSRT = 'PRESCODE' 
    AND OFNIVO IN (1, 2)
)

SELECT DISTINCT
    DTE24.CONDSRT,
    DTE24.CONTROLE,
    DTE24.WAARDEBEG,
    totaal.totaalx,
    totaal1.totaalof1,
    totaal2.totaalof2
FROM [RT_IPOIKAZ_ODS].[WinIKAZ].[DTE24],
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG, COUNT(WAARDEBEG) AS totaalx
    FROM SourceData
    WHERE OFNIVO IN (1,2)
    GROUP BY CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG
) AS totaal ON DTE24.CONTROLE = totaal.CONTROLE AND DTE24.WAARDEBEG = totaal.WAARDEBEG
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG, COUNT(WAARDEBEG) AS totaalof1
    FROM SourceData
    WHERE OFNIVO = 1
    GROUP BY CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG
) AS totaal1 ON DTE24.CONTROLE = totaal1.CONTROLE AND DTE24.WAARDEBEG = totaal1.WAARDEBEG
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG, COUNT(WAARDEBEG) AS totaalof2
    FROM SourceData
    WHERE OFNIVO = 2
    GROUP BY CONTROLE, WAARDEBEG
) AS totaal2 ON DTE24.CONTROLE = totaal2.CONTROLE AND DTE24.WAARDEBEG = totaal2.WAARDEBEG

ORDER BY 3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: definitely! Thanks a lot, also for the extra's. With the common table expression. I will read and master it.

Comment: I am glad that you found my answer useful. Please consider up-voting it and marking it as the accepted answer. Doing so will increase yours and my Stackoverflow reputation score, and will unlock other features on Stackoverflow. Thank you.